# Android custom seekbar/progressbar like this (see image)

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-progressbar, android-seekbar

I want to create one custom seekbar/progress bar like this..

[image: see the shape and three color]

Any idea or link how to achieve this ? (see the shape and three color)

Thanks.

Comment: Create your custom view.

Comment: thanks @azizbekian, any link or example to start with ?

Comment: start with [this](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Comment: thanks @pskink. you mean i need to create custom view which contains progressbar and image ? my concern is how we can change the shape of progressbar ? how that tracking ball of progressbar will work as displayed in image ?

Comment: so you need `Custom Drawing` - see again the link i posted - this is the lesson #2

Comment: @pskink thanks, learning lesson #2 :)

Answer (score 1):

you may try with this

[create your custom shape](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

[refer this github link](https://github.com/MarcinMoskala/ArcSeekBar?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6053) it will help you

[image]

```
<com.marcinmoskala.arcseekbar.ArcSeekBar
app:thumb="@drawable/thumb2"
app:progressColor="@color/colorAccent"
app:progressBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="100dp" />
```